# On render(), how does Django know which language to pick?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-i18n

I am just very curious. Django runs the following line:

```
email_body = get_template("applicant/email_with_token.txt").render(Context())
```

it runs it from `form_valid()` of a class-based view. New context is created based on a regular python dictionary. No parameters are passed, that come from a view, user, session, etc... Inside of the template there is `{% load i18n %}` and a bunch of context/variables.

Still, Django recognizes the language of the current session and applies appropriate translations.

So, where from does it know the session language?

Comment: Unless you've changed your settings.py file there should be a couple of line sin there that look like this: `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'` and `USE_I18N = True` those likely have something to do with it.

Comment: Did you read the documentation on [How Django discovers language preference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference)?

Comment: Yes, I was reading it, including the "... by following this algorithm" part. Unfortunately it still does not explain the case, since I don't pass the session anywhere.

Comment: Why would you need to pass the session anywhere? That explains that the choice is being done in the middleware, long before you get to the template rendering process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"... decides what translation object to install **in the current thread context**" [(source)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/middleware/locale/#LocaleMiddleware)

Simple as it is, the language is thread-wide, since one thread serves one request, and request knows about the language.